# Get a handle on the actual google map object

Tags: openlayers-3, ol3-google-maps

I'm trying to use the google places api on the same page as an openlayers map using olgm to serve and embedded google map.

I need to have a handle to the google map in order to construct the places api `PlacesService`:

```
var placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(gmap);
```

However, olgm encapsulates the google map and I can't work out how to get a reference to it:

```
olgm.OLGoogleMaps = function(options) {
    ...
    var gmap = new google.maps.Map(gmapEl, {
    ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: also, is there a debug version of the olgm code?

Comment: Yes: `ol3gm-debug.js`.  You can get it from: http://mapgears.github.io/ol3-google-maps/ (see the Zip file link on top right)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the Google Maps object if you have access to the olgm object:

```
var olGM = new olgm.OLGoogleMaps({map: map});
var gmap = olGM.getGoogleMapsMap();
```

For the debug version, if you are using the latest release (0.6 as of today), you can download it here, in the downloads section: https://github.com/mapgears/ol3-google-maps/releases/tag/v0.6

In the .zip you will find a file named `ol3gm-debug.js`

If you're building your own version, it should appear in the `dist` directory.

Comment: ol3gm extends ol3 to allow the integration of google maps, but it doesn't replace it.

Comment: it embeds ol3 within it's distribution @AlexandreDubé

Comment: What I meant is that it doesn't tries to replace ol3.  Yes, it includes it.